# How can i improve this filter ? this is working but i think that isnt the right way

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have those object arrays and it has to be a better way to to this, this filter is supposed to return only the items on the first array that contains the same name in the second array but only with those pre determined status

```js
const Array1 = [
  { id: 1, name: 'test1', status: 'STATUS1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'test2', status: 'STATUS2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'test3', status: 'STATUS3' },
  { id: 4, name: 'test4', status: 'STATUS4' }
];
const Array2 = [
  { id: 1, name: 'test1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'test2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'test3' }
];
let filteredOrders = Array1.filter(m =>
  Array2.find(s => s.name === m.name) && m.status.includes("STATUS1", "STATUS2")
)

console.log(filteredOrders)
```

Comment: Sounds like two filters, doesn't it?

Comment: Chain two filters?

Comment: You can't put two string arguments in `includes()`. I think you mean `["STATUS1", "STATUS2"].includes(m.status)`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with have multiple conditions connected with `&&` in the filter function. This code seems fine to me.

Comment: better means run faster, for you?

Comment: However, if `Array2` could be large, it would be better to make a `Set` of all the names and use that, instead of searching the array every time.

Comment: better doesnt necessarily means faster, it just means better, i think this is wrong for some reason

Comment: By "better" do you mean correct/actually working, or do you mean more efficient, or more maintainable...?

Comment: I made you a snippet and fixed your includes, but someone did not like that. So re-read [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68897669/how-can-i-improve-this-filter-this-is-working-but-i-think-that-isnt-the-right#comment121763134_68897669)

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks for the snippet, but why fix OP's broken code? That should be an answer, I'd think.

Comment: @ggorlen No, the question should be closed as a typo-type and deleted

Comment: why do you think it is wrong? Do you have any evidence of failure? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @mplungjan That's fine too, although it's less of a typo and more of a syntactical misunderstanding, I think that nonetheless has little value to future visitors. I voted to close as unclear because I don't know what "better" means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider breaking this down into two separate steps:

1. Create an hash of existing names in `Array2` to compare against (so you don't have to loop through it multiple times)

```
const names = Array2.reduce(function(map, obj) {
    map[obj.name] = true;
    return map;
}, {});
```

2. Then do your filtering:

```
const matching = Array1.filter( m =>
    names[m.name] && ["STATUS1", "STATUS2"].includes(m.status)
)
```

Also, a small note of distinction between the way you filtered by status and the way I did.

You wrote: `m.status.includes("STATUS1", "STATUS2")` which does a [string based matching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes). Basically, do any of these values appear (entirely or in-part) in the string I'm trying to match.

Which would mean that a record with a status value of "STATUS12" would return true since "STATUS1" appears in "STATUS12".

The version I provided uses [array based includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)() using the statuses you're trying to find as the array and doing a direct comparison against each status you're trying to match.

Answer (score 0):

First, Let's fix the code
`.includes()` can not take 2 inputs for searching in a string, the second parameter is used for specifying an offset, We'll replace this with `match` and a regex `/STATUS[1-2]/`

```js
m.status.includes("STATUS1", "STATUS2")
// becomes
m.status.match(/STATUS[1-2]/)
```

A better way to achieve what you're after is to create an array of names, and then just do 1 loop over the array that needs filtering.

```
const Array1 = [
  { id: 1, name: 'test1', status: 'STATUS1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'test2', status: 'STATUS2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'test3', status: 'STATUS3' },
  { id: 4, name: 'test4', status: 'STATUS4' }
];

const Array2 = [
  { id: 1, name: 'test1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'test2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'test3' }
];

// make an array that contains only the name value from each object in Array2
const Array2Names = Array2.map(i => i.name)

// filter Array1
let filteredOrders = Array1.reduce((a, i) => {
    if (Array2Names.includes(i.name) && i.status.match(/STATUS[1-2]/)) return [...a, i]
    else return a
}, [])

console.log(filteredOrders)
/* [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test1",
        "status": "STATUS1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "test2",
        "status": "STATUS2"
    }
] */
```

Comment: Nitpick: _"Let's fix the code `.includes()` can not take 2 inputs"_ It actually expects two arguments: [`Array.prototype.includes(searchElement, fromIndex)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) The second one is optional.

Comment: Ah correct, I'll update that! It was in reference as to how he was attempting to use it, Thanks :D